# django model's field include other objects' attribute

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website to learn the django framework. It's a website for a web development studio where you can customize the project that you need them to design.

My model architecture is:

Features: the smallest building block.
Bundle: a group of features that you want to include in your website.
project: the overall collection of features, that can include (or not) one bundle.

```
from django.db import models

class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2),
    description = models.TextField(),
    progress = models.IntegerField(),
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Bundle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(),
    features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature),



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is what I have so far, it's not complete but you can get a taste of what I want to do. The problem is:

I want to include a field in bundle and project that calculates the total cost of it. The field's value will be the sum of the features included in the features attribute of my bundle class.

How can I accomplish this? Can I create a field that is a list of objects' features?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Can I create a field that is a list of objects' features" For this, that manytomany relationship is enough (or if not just a foreignkey). You can calculate the sum using this very relation. That's why there exist manytomany, foreignkey, etc.

Comment: Great, how can I do it?

Comment: I mean, what is the right hand side of:

price = ???

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a field for the summation, then you can just use `DecimalField` like:

```
price_sum = DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

And using that `ManyToMany` relationship, you can just calculate the sum and save it in this field.

Answer (score 0):

The field *"that is a list of objects' features"* is the M2M field. I don't think you need create new fields, you can get the total price from view calculating over you current architecture:

```
# Here you have 'list' of features in boundle
boundle_object.features.all()
# And here you have the sum of prices
from django.db.models import Sum
boundle_object.features.aggregate(summation=Sum('price'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `Bundle` model like this:

```
class Bundle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(),
    features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature)

    @property
    def total_feature_price(self):
        sum = sum(self.features.all().values_list('price', flat=True))
        return sum    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then if you have a `Bundle` object, you could do:

```
cost = bundle.total_feature_price
```